# TypeError: $(...).colorbox is not a function when calling colorbox with element ID

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using colorbox to send ajax request. When I initially open the colorbox it works fine, but when I close it and reopen it second time or more, it gives the following error:

> TypeError: $(...).colorbox is not a function

I've replaced the $ with jQuery but the error is still the same.

> TypeError: jQuery(...).colorbox is not a function

I've the following code:

```
function equipmentButton(event) {
    disabledEventPreventDefault(event);

    if ($("#Briefing_scheduled_date").val() == "") {
        alert("You can't add briefing equipment without specifying " + wordForBriefing + " date.");

        return false;
    }

    $('#equipmentPopup').colorbox({
        ajax: true,
        width: "620px",
        height: "450px",
        href: showEquipment,
        data: function () {
            return {
                briefingId: $("#briefing_id").val(),
                briefingDate: $("#Briefing_scheduled_date").val(),
                briefingEndDate: $("#Briefing_scheduled_end_date").val(),
                briefingEquipments: $('#BriefingEquipments').val()
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You appear to be missing some references to JavaScript files. Show where your page links to your jQuery and ColorBox javascript files.

Comment: Make sure you have your Javascript in the correct order

Comment: That means you don't have colorbox in your page or you just initialized it before colorbox is available.

Comment: there is a button on my page,  on its click I call a function (the one which I've given above).
On page load, first time when I click the button colorbox popup open and I didn't get any error, but when I close it and tries to reopen it gives me the type error.
I'm loading all my .js file when I load the main page.